# How can I password-protect my /sidekiq route (i.e. require authentication for the Sidekiq::Web tool)?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, rescue, sidekiq

I am using sidekiq in my rails application.
By Default, Sidekiq can be accessed by anybody by appending "/sidekiq" after the url.
I want to password protect / authenticate only the sidekiq part. How can i do that?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Put the following into your sidekiq initializer

```
require 'sidekiq'
require 'sidekiq/web'

Sidekiq::Web.use(Rack::Auth::Basic) do |user, password|
  # Protect against timing attacks:
  # - See https://codahale.com/a-lesson-in-timing-attacks/
  # - See https://thisdata.com/blog/timing-attacks-against-string-comparison/
  # - Use & (do not use &&) so that it doesn't short circuit.
  # - Use digests to stop length information leaking
  Rack::Utils.secure_compare(::Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(user), ::Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(ENV["SIDEKIQ_USER"])) &
  Rack::Utils.secure_compare(::Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(password), ::Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(ENV["SIDEKIQ_PASSWORD"]))
end
```

And in the routes file:

```
mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
```

Comment: BTW-I put the following in my Gemfile so I wouldn't have to manually require sidekiq and sidekiq/web in both the initializer and the routes.rb file:  "gem 'sidekiq', require: ['sidekiq', 'sidekiq/web']"

Comment: At least in my app running Rails 5, it wasn't necessary for me to wrap the `mount` call with the `authenticate` block.

Comment: As documented on Sidekiq project, you probably want to use
`ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils.secure_compare(::Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(user), ::Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(ENV["SIDEKIQ_USER"])) & ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils.secure_compare(::Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(password), ::Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(ENV["SIDEKIQ_PASSWORD"]))` to compare username and password.

Comment: WARNING! Using `==` operator exposes the application to timing attacks. Any attacker can eventually find out what the password is by guessing each character one by one based on request processing times. Use `ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils.secure_compare`, `Devise.secure_compare`, or alike.

Comment: You dont need `authenticate` block. If you are not using devise, it gives error on rails 6

Comment: You dont need authenticate block for Rails 5 neither.

Comment: Edited out the `authenticate` block just now.  I can personally vouch it's not needed as I have this solution working in a couple of Rails 6 apps already.

Comment: If you're using `ENV['SIDEKIQ_USER']` or `Rails.application.credentials.dig(:sidekiq, :username)`, you run the risk of not having set the environment variable or included the master key in production.

This scenario can lead to getting the error `TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String)`. Instead, use `ENV.fetch('SIDEKIQ_USER')` or `Rails.application.credentials.fetch(:sidekiq).fetch(:username)` to ensure a missing value raises a more helpful error message.

Answer (score 32):

Sorry to late to the party, but [Sidekiq's wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring) recommends the following for Devise:

To allow any authenticated `User`:

```
# config/routes.rb
authenticate :user do
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
end
```

To restrict access to `User.admin?`

```
# config/routes.rb
authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.admin? } do
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
end
```

[This wiki post](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring) also has many other security schemes.

This was tested using Rails 5.1.3, Devise 4.3 and Sidekiq  5.0

Comment: Thanks for the links to the good practices on the Sidekiq wiki, Tom!

Comment: Any documentation to show how to RSpec test this?

Comment: @tomAranda did you every figure out how to rspec test this?

Comment: I have written an rspec for this and I don't plan to in the near future.

Answer (score 15):

See "Security" under https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring

> Sidekiq::Web uses [Rack::Protection](https://github.com/sinatra/rack-protection) to protect your application against typical web attacks (such as [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), etc). Rack::Protection would invalidate your session and raise `Forbidden` error if it finds that your request doesn't satisfy security requirements. One of the possible situations is having your application working behind a reverse proxy and not passing important headers to it (`X-Forwarded-For`,`X-Forwarded-Proto`). Such situation and solution could be found [in this article](http://www.sourcediver.org/blog/2015/07/01/rack-protection-and-nginx/) and [issue #2560](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2560)...

Answer (score 13):

If you are rolling your own custom authentication, then you can use the below example which is referenced in the docs [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring#restful-authentication-or-sorcery).

```
# lib/admin_constraint.rb
class AdminConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    return false unless request.session[:user_id]
    user = User.find request.session[:user_id]
    user && user.admin?
  end
end

# config/routes.rb
require 'sidekiq/web'
require 'admin_constraint'
mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq', :constraints => AdminConstraint.new
```

Comment: This answer was helpful although I'm sure if we can avoid the extra queries each time `sidekiq/stats` is requested which is quite often at the moment.

Comment: In rails 7 I'm seeing that the constant won't be findable by default unless it's in /app. That is, app/constraints/

Answer (score 11):

If you're using Devise (or other Warden-based authentication), you can do this, supposing you have an AdminUser model in your app.

```
# config/routes.rb
# This defines the authentication constraint
constraint = lambda do |request|
               request.env['warden'].authenticate!({ scope: :admin_user })
             end

# This mounts the route using the constraint.
# You could use any other path to make it less obvious
constraints constraint do
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
end
```

Comment: can I put this constraint at any other place? I mean instead of putting it in routes.rb

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is good, but I think that it can be implemented more securely, as [Sidekiq documentation mentions](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring#rails-http-basic-auth-from-routes)  (it got edited to demonstrate the right solution after I posted).

To protect your app against timing attacks, use `ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils.secure_compare`.

- See https://codahale.com/a-lesson-in-timing-attacks/
- See https://thisdata.com/blog/timing-attacks-against-string-comparison/

Also, use `&` (do not use `&&`) so that it doesn't short circuit.

And finally, use digests to stop length information leaking (default of `secure_compare` in Active Support 5).

So, in an initializer file, typically in `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb` in Rails projects, depending of your version of Active Support/Rails, write the following.

**Active Support 5+**: Thanks to [Rails PR #24510](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/24510), parameters passed to `secure_compare` are going through `Digest::SHA256.hexdigest` by default.

```rb
require 'active_support/security_utils'
require 'sidekiq'
require 'sidekiq/web'

Sidekiq::Web.use(Rack::Auth::Basic) do |user, password|
  # Protect against timing attacks:
  # - See https://codahale.com/a-lesson-in-timing-attacks/
  # - See https://thisdata.com/blog/timing-attacks-against-string-comparison/
  # - Use & (do not use &&) so that it doesn't short circuit.
  # - Use digests to stop length information leaking
  ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils.secure_compare(user, ENV["SIDEKIQ_ADMIN_USER"]) &
    ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils.secure_compare(password, ENV["SIDEKIQ_ADMIN_PASSWORD"])
end
```

**Active Support 4**:

```rb
require 'active_support/security_utils'
require 'sidekiq'
require 'sidekiq/web'

Sidekiq::Web.use(Rack::Auth::Basic) do |user, password|
  # Protect against timing attacks:
  # - See https://codahale.com/a-lesson-in-timing-attacks/
  # - See https://thisdata.com/blog/timing-attacks-against-string-comparison/
  # - Use & (do not use &&) so that it doesn't short circuit.
  # - Use digests to stop length information leaking
  ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils.secure_compare(
    ::Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(user),
    ::Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(ENV["SIDEKIQ_ADMIN_USER"])
  ) &
    ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils.secure_compare(
      ::Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(password),
      ::Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(ENV["SIDEKIQ_ADMIN_PASSWORD"])
    )
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Sorcery](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery) for authentication, here's [how to use Rails routes constraints](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/wiki/Routes-Constraints) to protect certain routes.

---

Copied here from the sorcery wiki for redundancy:

This tutorial shows how to use Rails routes constraints with Sorcery gem. Thanks to [@anthonator](https://github.com/anthonator) for writing it!

First, define `UserConstraint` module that will be used for all constraints:

```
module RouteConstraints::UserConstraint
  def current_user(request)
    User.find_by_id(request.session[:user_id])
  end
end
```

Then, having that module defined, you can specify specific constraint classes. In these examples, first route will work only if there's no user logged in, the second will work only for logged user who is an admin:

```
class RouteConstraints::NoUserRequiredConstraint
  include RouteConstraints::UserConstraint

  def matches?(request)
    !current_user(request).present?
  end
end

class RouteConstraints::AdminRequiredConstraint
  include RouteConstraints::UserConstraint

  def matches?(request)
    user = current_user(request)
    user.present? && user.is_admin?
  end
end
```

Finally, you can add the constraints to the `config/routes.rb`:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  # other routes …

  root :to => 'admin#dashboard', :constraints => RouteConstraints::AdminRequiredConstraint.new
  root :to => 'home#welcome', :constraints => RouteConstraints::NoUserRequiredConstraint.new

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to add something like CanCan and special access based on roles.

Answer (score 0):

with ability to use devise username/password

> this will also work for the APIs

#config/initializers/sidekiq.rb

```
require "sidekiq/web"

Sidekiq::Web.use Rack::Auth::Basic do |username, password|
    User.find_by(username: username)&.valid_password?(password)
end
```

#config/routes.rb

```
mount Sidekiq::Web => "/sidekiq"
```

Answer (score 0):

With active admin
write this in config/routes.rb file

```
  authenticate :admin_user do
    mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
  end
```