# Rails 5 Protect Sidekiq UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, sidekiq

I'm trying to protect the Sidekiq UI with Devise. I'm running Rails 5.1, Devise 4.3 and Sidekiq 5.0. I tried the following post:

[How can I password-protect my /sidekiq route (i.e. require authentication for the Sidekiq::Web tool)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265421/how-can-i-password-protect-my-sidekiq-route-i-e-require-authentication-for-th)

but I get the following error:

```
Undefined method failure_app for nil:NilClass
```

My routes file looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  constraint = lambda do |request|
    request.env['warden'].authenticate!({ scope: :admin_user })
  end

  constraints constraint do
    mount Sidekiq::Web => '/admin/sidekiq'
  end

  devise_for :users
  resources :users
end
```

How can I protect Sidekiq UI with Devise on Rails 5.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I stumbled across this [page](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring#Authentication) that outlines how to secure the Web UI with Devise:

```
Devise

Allow any authenticated User

# Allow any user access
authenticate :user do
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
end

# Allow only admin users
authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.admin? } do
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
end
```

I've confirmed that this works with Rails 5.1 and Devise 4.3.

Comment: thanks a lot for this, works in Rails 7 too, saved me time :)